# Get 1st day of next month

Tags: php, date, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to find first day of the next month and remain days to this date with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777384/how-to-find-first-day-of-the-next-month-and-remain-days-to-this-date-with-php)

I have this to get 1st day of current month

```
$_SERVER['dataInicio'] = date('Y') . "-" . date('m') . "-" . "1";
```

I need something similar to get 1st day of NEXT month

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems like a duplicate or similar post to this for the next month

but for the next month something like this if you want to use strtotime

```
date("m/l/Y", strtotime(date('m', strtotime('+1 month')).'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'));
```

this will return

12/Saturday/2012 if you want just the days name just set the date format to l (lower case L)

`date("l", strtotime(date('m', strtotime('+1 month')).'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'));`

[How to find first day of the next month and remaining days till this date with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777384/how-to-find-first-day-of-the-next-month-and-remain-days-to-this-date-with-php)

or this

[In PHP, is there an easy way to get the first and last date of a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589/in-php-is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-the-first-and-last-date-of-a-month)

Comment: I would do it like this instead, it won't fail in December. strtotime(date('m', strtotime('+1 month')) . '/01/' . date('Y', strtotime('+1 month')));

Comment: @Halfstop great point i'll update my answer

Comment: I run this code on 2017-DEC-15 and its return 01/Sunday/2017 so it came me to 12 month back it not move me to 2018. so this technique not gives the correct output.
i found a solution for it:

$date_obj=date_create("first day of next month");
echo $date = date_format($date_obj,"Y-m-d H:i:s");

Comment: I use a variation of this: date('Y-m-01', strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' + 1 month'))

Comment: strtotime('first day of next month'); Wouldn't this be the easiest thing to use?

Answer (score 40):

```
$date = new DateTime('now');

$date->modify('first day of next month');
echo $date->format('D') . '\n';

$date->modify('first day of this month');
echo $date->format('D') . '\n';
```

Comment: Looks good, but if you add some comments to your code it will be even more helpfull to understand your proposal.

Comment: The very simplest way : $firstDayNextMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of next month'));

Comment: This should be the right answer... where can I get all the modify string codes?

Answer (score 4):

```
$_SERVER['dataInicio'] = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')+1, 1, date('Y')));
```

Should do what you're wanting.

Comment: in december 2012 the 1st day of next month should be  2013-1-1

Comment: @CarlosMartins - the code works for any month. See the mktime documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php