# Last day of next month date timestamp in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I'm using the following function to get the current timestamp:

```
$created_timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

But how do I get a timestamp for the last day of next month. So for example, if it is the 15th of September to get the 31st of October. Including all the hours, minutes and seconds as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$created_timestamp = date("Y-m-t  H:i:s", strtotime("+1 month"));
```

`t` - number of days in the given month

Comment: This will fail if you test if today is "2019-01-30" for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
date("Y-m-t H:i:s",strtotime("+1 month")) ;
```